# Example of sequence which has every point of [0,1] as limit point if it exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I wanted to find 
1)Example of the sequence which has every point of [0,1] as limit point if it exists 
2)Example of the sequence which has every rational point of [0,1] as limit point if it exists 
Sorry, I thought but I did not get example.Any  Help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there a sequence containing every rational in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sequence $\{k \sqrt{2} - \lfloor k\sqrt{2} \rfloor, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\lfloor \bullet \rfloor$ is *floor* function (integer part of the number).

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Yes Sir .

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2 n$ is as good a sequence as any.

Comment: Thanks A Lot and how to do for rational number ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.  Are you looking for a sequence that has ***only*** rational points as limit points?

Comment: Yes sir I mean same

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2799102/72694).

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the second question, if a sequence of elements of $[0,1]$ is such that every rational in $[0,1]$ is a limit point, then every element of $[0,1]$ is a limit point, since the rationals are dense. So, it is not possible that *only* the rationals are limit points.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sir .I got Now